# How to get inside data in Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<Map> returnUserMap() async {
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    Map userMap = {
      "UserName": currentUser.displayName,
      "UserEmail": currentUser.email,
      "UserUrl": currentUser.photoUrl
    };
    print("1");
    print(userMap);
    return userMap;
  }
```

return value type is Instance of 'Future>'.
I want to get a UserName, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `returnUserMap()` returns a `Future<Map>`. I suspect that the error you describe is not in the code snippet you copied.

Whenever the task to be performed may take some time, you will receive a future. You can wait for futures in an async function with *await*.

It is therefore recommended to use a so-called FutureBuilder in your build() function:

```dart
FutureBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
   future: _auth.currentUser(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     if (snapshot.hasData) {
       final FirebaseUser user = snapshot.data;
       if (user.displayName == null || user.displayName.isEmpty())
         return text(currentUser.email); // display email if name isn't set
       return text(currentUser.displayName);
     }
     if (snapshot.hasError) {
       return text(snapshot.error);
     }
     return text('loading...');
   },
),
```

If you want to have the displayName outside your build() function, the following code should do the job when you are inside of an async function:

```dart
final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
final String displayName = user.displayName;
print('the displayName of the current user is: $displayName');
```

And this code when you are in a normal function:

```dart
_auth.currentUser().then((FirebaseUser user) {
     String displayName = user.displayName;
     print('displayName: $displayName');
}).catchError((error) {
     print('error: ' + error.toString());
});
```

I think it's worth watching the following video for further understanding: 
[Async/Await - Flutter in Focus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY)